# How to centrally manage 6+ network printers (Small Business)

Tags: network-printer

We have around 6 network printers in our office right now. The main issue is that Windows seems to automatically reinstall them periodically (and automatically) and then they lose their name that is associated with them.

I am considering installing them (via network) on one machine (a VM acting as a server) and sharing them from that machine. Then on all the other machines setting them up to use the one machine's shares.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: My networking knowledge is limited, but wouldn't you typically install these printers on the domain controller/active directory? Why do you need a VM?

Comment: We don't have a domain controller, and al we have is a NAS for a "Server". They are all stand alone work stations. I would like to have a domain controller but then I would again need a server and probably a VM to run it on. We only have 10 workstations and 3 laptops in the company.

Comment: Ah ok. Then I guess your method would work, but perhaps wait for someone with more expertise than me to confirm...

Comment: "Is there a simpler way to do this?" Nope, that's how a print server works. You setup printers on the Print Server, share them out, and then access them from the workstations via the shares on the print server.  Voting to close, as "Is there a simpler way?" is too broad of a question.

Comment: Ummm that's answer not a comment

Comment: Use reserved or static IPs.